# is CPU usage in Apache Spark limited?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I recently discovered that adding parallel computing (e.g. using parallel-collections) inside UDFs increases performance considerable even when running spark in `local[1]` mode or using Yarn with 1 executor and 1 core.

E.g. in `local[1]` mode, the Spark-Jobs consumes as much CPU as possible (i.e. 800% if I have 8 cores, measured using `top`).

This seems strange because I thought Spark (or yarn) limits the CPU usage per Spark application?

So I wonder why that is and whether it's recommended to use parallel-processing/mutli-threading in spark or should I stick to sparks parallelizing pattern?

Here an example to play with (times measured in yarn client-mode with 1 instance and 1 core)

```
case class MyRow(id:Int,data:Seq[Double])

// create dataFrame
val rows = 10
val points = 10000
import scala.util.Random.nextDouble
val data = {1 to rows}.map{i => MyRow(i, Stream.continually(nextDouble()).take(points))}
val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF().repartition($"id").cache()

df.show() // trigger computation and caching

// some expensive dummy-computation for each array-element
val expensive = (d:Double) => (1 to 10000).foldLeft(0.0){case(a,b) => a*b}*d

val serialUDF = udf((in:Seq[Double]) => in.map{expensive}.sum)
val parallelUDF = udf((in:Seq[Double]) => in.par.map{expensive}.sum)

df.withColumn("sum",serialUDF($"data")).show() // takes ~ 10 seconds
df.withColumn("sum",parallelUDF($"data")).show() // takes ~ 2.5 seconds
```

Comment: When you are running in Yarn cluster you can limit usage of cores based on yarn configuration.

Comment: I think Spark would limit the number of threads created by Spark processes (ie the task scheduler), but it cannot stop scala's parallel collections to create new threads from the thread that is assigned to the task.

Answer (score 2):

Spark does not limit CPU directly, instead it defines the number of concurrent threads spark creates. So for local[1] it would basically run one task at a time in parallel. When you are doing in.par.map{expensive} you are creating threads which spark does not manage and therefore are not handled by this limit. i.e. you told spark to limit itself to a single thread and then created other threads without spark knowing it.

In general, it is not a good idea to do parallel threads inside of a spark operation. Instead, it would be better to tell spark how many threads it can work with and make sure you have enough partitions for parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Spark are configuration of CPU usage 
examople

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster("local[2]")
             .setAppName("CountingSheep")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

change the local[*] it will utilization all of your CPU cores.