# spark.task.cpus changed runtime - speedup pairwise comparisons

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've read some of the previous posts and sadly I think I can't do what I would like to do, but maybe there is a recent solution that I don't know about. I would like at a certain point to perform some parallel operations within a map using the parallel collections provided by the Scala standard library. However, I understood that I should set at the beginning of my Spark execution the spark.task.cpus to assign to each task a sufficient number of cores. My configuration is made of 14 nodes with 8 cores each.

Within a map, I have two collections of points that should be compared using the Euclidean distance to check if at least one pair respects a distance threshold. Consequently, I end up with something like:

```
collection1.exists(point1 =>
    collection2.exists(point2 => dist(point1, point2) <= threshold))
```

which represents a very heavy step if the comparison is not positive at the beginning. However, if the collections are parallel, they can be tested much faster. Finally notice that I can't explode the collections or reduce their size too much due to an excessive replication that would occur in the previous steps, in which case the shuffle time would be the bottleneck.

Suggestions?
If I'm missing something in the problem description tell me and I'll add all the useful information required.

Thanks

EDIT: I add an example to clarify my scenario.

Example:
I start from a collection:

```
{(1, col_1), (2, col_2), (3, col_3)}
```

I want to perform the pairwise comparisons (increasing second key), so I would end up with a new collection:

```
{((1,2),(col_1, col_2)), ((1,3),(col_1,col_3)), ((2,3), (col_2, col_3))}
```

Now, the new collection is filtered using the previous test, which is O(|col_i|*|col_j|). In order to avoid to create bottlenecks in the execution, I decided to limit the size of the collections associated to each test. However, this leads to the creation of multiple entries associated to each key initially. For example:

```
{(1, col_1_a), (1, col_1_b), (1, col_1_c), (2, col_2_a), (2, col_2_b), (3, col_3_a), (3, col_3_b), (3, col_3_c), (3, col_3_d)}
```

and also the number of entries in the comparison collection increases:

```
{((1,2), (col_1_a, col_2_a)), ((1,2), (col_1_a, col_2_b)), ..., ((2,3), (col_2_b, col_3_d))}
```

There is a tradeoff between the maximum length of each collection, which limits the time required for a single test, and the total number of tests generated, which increases the shuffle required to create all the pairs. To maximize the performances in my opinion it would be convenient to use parallel collections and increase the maximum size of each col_i, because it would lead to the maximum core usage instead of being limited by the number of tasks assigned to each executor. Is it correct? Increasing the number of partitions in the Spark collection would lead to the same result? I see that progressively there are less and less remaining tasks and each machine is not fully used.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Sounds like a XY problem to me. _if the collections are parallel, they can be tested much faster_. If Spark parallelism is increase, you can increase throughput as well... Why bother with parallel collections?

Comment: In my experience (using yarn), you don't have to set spark.task.cpus in your case. I also worked with parallel collections inside spark (remote) code, and it seems that just all available cores on the executors are used, no even though spark.task.cpus was set to 1. This means that in this case, resource allocation isn't "fair" anymore

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619875/is-cpu-usage-in-apache-spark-limited

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I think you misinterpreting the meaning of the parameter. It is used to inform resource manager, that more cores will be used, and to schedule tasks correcting for that. It is not about limiting things. There was a nice answer on SO about it, but I cannot find it right now...

Comment: So if I leave spark.task.cpus = 1 and then I try to parallelize the collections to perform the test, in my scenario 8 cores would be assigned to each test? However, Spark would think that a single core would be assigned to each task. This would lead to an excessive amount of concurrent threads per machine because the scheduler would produce 8 concurrent tasks aswell, possibly leading to 64 threads in a 8 core machine. Am I wrong?

Comment: Added an example to clarify.